# Rails route to specific path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In `config/routes.rb` I wrote like below

```
resources :scrapped_movies do
  get :check_match
end
```

Basically, Rails send to show after `get` However, I just want to redirect this to index

In controller,

```
def check_match

  type = params[:type]

  crawl_id = params[:k1]
  watcha_id = params[:k2]
  # save params to redis

end
```

check_match just takes params, and I do not have to actually show this so I’d like to return to index. How can I do this?
If I just put `redirect_to` in check_match function, `Rails` give me there is no `show` error.

Comment: can you paste the full error when you use redirect_to please?

Comment: ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template admin/scrapped_movies/show

Comment: also the output of `rake routes` please, seems like you are missing add your show method to routes.rb. Edit your question and add the output there

Comment: @jh.shin Shouldn't you be using simply `index` action in your controller? In case you just want to show `index` view, you can do `render 'index'` in your controller. Basically you would route to particular action, but render `index` view - a bit weird, but can be done.

Comment: @matiss but just putting render 'index' showed same result. `get` method always tries to be routed to `show`

Comment: @jh.shin I think your routes are not defined right. If you do [CRUD](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions), then you just do `resources :scrapped_movies` in your `routes`, but then in controller you use some of CRUD actions, e.g., index. If you do custom routes, then I believe you have to [specify your route like here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources).

Comment: `redirect_to action: :index, status: 303`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`render :show` and `redirect_to` do very different things.

```
render :show
```

Renders a template named show, it will lookup the template based on the controller name (`app/views/scrapped_movies/show.html.{erb|slim|haml}`). And returns it as the response body.

```
redirect_to action: :show, id: 1
```

redirects the browser by sending a `302 Found` status and sets the location header to `/scrapped_movies/1`.

Additionally the show action in Rails is for displaying a single resource. What you want is most likely the index:

```
redirect_to action: :index
# or
redirect_to scrapped_movies_path
```